# AdControl lags my application, can I optimize it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

In Visual Studio I've created a "Windows Phone Silverlight and XNA Application" and added Microsoft AdControl to to the XNA part of the game.

But I experience huge lag spikes resulting in hang in my game. It also get worse when you are using the phone net and not a WLAN connected to internet.

I can't have these spikes since they destroy the gameplay, they can be ut to a few seconds (1-2 seconds)

The code im using is from microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873087(v=msads.20).aspx

I might do a workerthread for the `AdComponent.Current.Update(e.ElapsedTime);` part and only do it once each 2 seconds or so, but im guessing the Update does a network call and is threaded and would not anything to say to thread this function :/

Comment: My first guess would be that you have a single thread doing all the job, and when you connection is a bit behind, it blocks everything. Of course, there is no real way to know without you posting some codes and giving more informations.

Comment: How about some code demonstrating the problem? Your call to AdControl?

Comment: @Marc-André Jutras im using standard code from the example... Im guessing AdComponent.Current.Update(e.ElapsedTime); uses a network control and is already threaded